# Exporting quoted variables from result of command

Tags: bash

I have a command that returns a string with a environment variable in the form of:

```
foo="foo bar"
```

The value of `foo` should be `bar` not `"bar"` however I cannot work out how to get bash to play along with exporting this:

```
$ export `echo 'foo="foo bar"'`
$ env | grep foo
foo="foo bar"
```

The desired behaviour is:

```
$ export foo="foo bar"
$ env | grep foo
foo=foo bar
```

The quotes are needed as variables can have spaces as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a string such as `s`:

```
$ s='foo="bar bar"'
```

To make and export an environment variable `foo` while avoiding `eval`, try:

```
$ declare -x "${s//\"/}"
```

We can verify that it worked with:

```
$ env | grep foo
foo=bar bar
```

*This, of course, assumes that there are no `"` inside the value of the variable.*

Notes:

1. `declare` creates a variable assignment as per the supplied string.  `declare -x` both creates and *exports* the variable.
2. `${s//\"/}` removes all double-quotes from the value of `s`.